# How to store BLOB to the sqlite database

Tags: database, sqlite, storage, blob

please help, im new to android i dont know many basics.
IM USING this code to store my powerpoint files as a BLOB. but when i run this. the database wont show anything even the filename as a list. how to store the blob properly WITHOUT using DBHELPER. because i started not using DBHELPER and im already quite far now from my project. just want to pass this project.

```
String filename = FilesInFolder.get(position);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/" + filename);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            byte[] buffer =new byte[1024];
            int read;
            while ((read = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                baos.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            baos.flush();
            byte[] fileByteArray = baos.toByteArray();

            notesDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                    PPT_TABLE_NAME + " (pptName,pptFile)" + 
                    " Values ('"+filename+"','"+fileByteArray+"');");
```

this is how i code my database

```
notesDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                PPT_TABLE_NAME + 
                " ( " + BaseColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,pptName VARCHAR,pptFile BLOB);");
```

and this is how i try to view it as a list

```
Cursor c = notesDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +
            PPT_TABLE_NAME, null);



    if (c != null ) {
        if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String pptid = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID.toString()));
                String pptname = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("pptName"));

                results.add(pptid + " " + pptname);
            }while (c.moveToNext());
        } 
    }

    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,results));
```

PLEASE HELP im still new to android..

Answer (score 1):

You cannot easily insert a byte array directly into a string.

To insert blobs, you should use a function that can handle byte arrays, such as the [insert method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29):

```java
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("pptName", filename);
cv.put("pptFile", fileByteArray);
notesDB.insert(PPT_TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
```